# Rust multiple mutable self borrowing from method calls

Tags: rust

I am learning Rust. For my first program, I wrote this code to maintain data about a partial ordering:

```
use std::collections::{HashMap, HashSet};

struct Node {
    num_before: usize,
    successors: HashSet<String>,
}

impl Node {
    fn new() -> Node {
        Node {
            num_before: 0,
            successors: HashSet::new(),
        }
    }
}

pub struct PartialOrdering {
    node: HashMap<String, Node>,
}

impl PartialOrdering {
    pub fn new() -> PartialOrdering {
        PartialOrdering {
            node: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn get_node(&mut self, name: &String) -> &mut Node {
        self.node.entry(name.clone()).or_insert_with(Node::new)
    }

    pub fn add_order(&mut self, before: &String, after: &String) {
        let mut before_node = self.get_node(before);
        if after != before {
            let mut after_node = self.get_node(after);
            if before_node.successors.insert(after.clone()) {
                after_node.num_before += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Compiling this code produces this error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> main.rs:35:25
   |
33 |         let before_node = self.get_node(before);
   |                           ---- first mutable borrow occurs here
34 |         if after != before {
35 |             let mut after_node = self.get_node(after);
   |                                  ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
36 |             if before_node.successors.insert(after.clone()) {
   |                ---------------------- first borrow later used here
```

Admittedly I am new to the Rust borrowing rules, but this problem has me stumped. Please tell me what I am doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: That your nodes hold references to their "successors", and a count of their "predecessors" (thus how many references are held to them—presumably so that no node is dropped while a predecessor still holds a reference to it?), is strikingly reminiscent of [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/alloc/rc/struct.Rc.html), the standard library's ref-counted pointer.  Using that instead would enable you to take ownership of cheap copies of the node pointers, and thus not hold onto mutable borrows.

Comment: However, mutating the data pointed at by an `Rc` requires "interior mutability" (i.e. *run-time*, rather than compile-time, borrow checking) which can be achieved with [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html).  Putting it together, you'd have `Rc<RefCell<Node>>` (albeit `Node` itself would no longer need to contain the fields shown in your example above).

Comment: @eggyal `RwLock` and `Mutex` also provide run-time borrow-checking at a bit of a higher level. These types are implemented using `UnsafeCell`, as is `RefCell`---when it comes to interior mutability in rust, [all roads point to `UnsafeCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html).

Comment: To clarify the purpose of the `num_before` field, this code is from a Rust version of the [tsort](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages//man1/tsort.1p.html) utility. The partial ordering of the tokens is created by calling `add_order` for each pair of tokens read from input. For each token, the `num_before` field is basically a count of the number of tokens known to be before it in the partial ordering, which is useful for generating the `tsort` output.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in Rust it is forbidden to take more than one mutable reference (`&mut`) to an object at a time (see [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.8.0/book/references-and-borrowing.html) for details). Your `get_node()` takes `&mut self` and uses it to obtain an `&mut Node` contained in `self` (where `self` is a `PartialOrdering`). This causes the mutable borrow of `self` to exist for as long as the value returned by `get_node()` exists, preventing other calls to `get_node()`. This means that you can't have `before_node: &mut Node` and `after_node: &mut Node` in the same scope, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for your clear and timely response. I revised the code so that `before_node` and `after_node` are in separate scopes, and everything worked fine.

I am **really** impressed that the Rust compiler detected that the `get_node` return value is a reference to part of `self`, and hence counts as a mutual reference.

Comment: Happy to help @FrankLhota! If you want to get a better intuition for what the borrow checker is doing here, you might want to read about [lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.9.0/book/lifetimes.html) (more advanced stuff [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/2018-edition/ch19-02-advanced-lifetimes.html)).